# SIM900A GSM/GPRS Shield Transaction per minute

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gsm

I'm planning to buy SIM900A GSM/GPRS Shield for Arduino Uno. I wanted to create an application that sends SMS to a list of mobile numbers, let's say 1000 mobile numbers. Is it applicable to use SIM900A GSM/GPRS shield for bulk messaging? Did anyone of you tested the sms transaction sent per second/minute using this shield? I accept any suggestion that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sound like you need an online sms gateway ([.e.g. message bird](https://www.messagebird.com/en/sms-gateway)) .

Comment: Yep, but this is only for my testing purposes for a few mobile numbers. Thanks

Comment: "Did anyone of you tested the sms transaction sent per second/minute using this shield?" This depends on the service provider, the radio network, more than the SIM900A.